# Extract two characters with duplication

Tags: ruby, split, character

I want to split characters like this

Input:
`12345678`

Output that I wanted:
`=> [1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6],[6,7],[7,8]`

How to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Enumerable#each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) may help:

```
str = "12345678"
out = str.chars.each_cons(2).to_a
#=> [["1", "2"], ["2", "3"], ["3", "4"], ["4", "5"], ["5", "6"], ["6", "7"], ["7", "8"]]
out2 = str.chars.map(&:to_i).each_cons(2).to_a
#=> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8]]
```